# How To Integrate a AAC Parser into Android source code?

Tags: android-framework

Please explain me about what an AACExtractor.cpp is all about codewise.

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer will not help the asker it will help other answer seekers .

AAC extractor.cpp is part of libstagefright.so , the stagefright media framework that handles playing of audio in android from  .
AAC extractor is being used by awesome player.cpp which controls audio/video playback.
Its expected from AACextractor class 
   to help identify if the file is an "aacfile" (SniffAAC function )

it needs to implement methods that

extract information pertaining to meta-data (album art, artist etc.,)

extract necessary information from the file that is to be given to the codec 
(sampling rate channels, initialize decoder , )

extract a frame and give it to the decoder .(support functions that implement seeking to particular frame etc.,)

These functions are used by other functions to get their work done.
This is an overview .The best way to understand is by printing logs .
Hope this helps

For more details look at 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-porting
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-framework